# Draw border on top of another application window

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm need to draw border on top another application's window (the main purpose is to highlight window user chooses from running applications list). I'm trying to draw border on top of native window border, but the border isn't drawn. Here is the code:

```
HPEN framePen = ::CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255, 0, 0));
HWND handle = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

WINDOWPLACEMENT winPlacement;
GetWindowPlacement(handle, &winPlacement);
if (winPlacement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
{
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE);
}

SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
SetForegroundWindow(handle);

PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rect = {};
::GetClientRect(handle, &rect);
HDC hdc = ::BeginPaint(handle, &ps);
::SelectObject(hdc, framePen);
::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
::EndPaint(handle, &ps);
```

In this example used handle of cmd window, but in fact it doesn't matter.
Could you please tell why border isn't drawn and how to draw it?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't just paint on somebody else's window like that. You need to create a transparent window that you place in the same place as the other window, and draw the border on that

Comment: You mean I need to create WNDCLASSA object with transparent background, then call RegisterClass for this object, then place this window on handle's window and then draw border on newly created window, right?

Comment: Does this API serve your purpose? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex

Comment: @Soonts, looks fine...even very fine, but is it possible to change the color of flashing?

Comment: Nope, the color depends on the Windows theme. Also, `FlashWindowEx` won't work for custom windows, which draw the title bar on their own.

Comment: @zett42, so I need to use advice of David? Is there example of such approach?

Comment: Have a look at [layered windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows). Simplest way: draw rectangle with a fill color that you pass as color key for `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`. This way only the border of the rectangle will be visible, while the inside will be transparent.

Comment: @zett42, I've just read about layered windows. It looks like possible solution, but I can't understand the way I should use them to solve my problem. Could you please provide some code samples or links to examples of how to use them as you described?

Comment: I will give an example if I find some time in the evening.

Comment: @zett42, thanks. Hope you'll find some time for this. I tried to create it by myself , but it didn't work properly.

Comment: In the updated code you are calling `SetWindowPos` for cmd window with `SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS`, so it can happen that it receives the message *after* your frame window is shown. Remove the flag and it should work.

Comment: @zett42, thanks. Now that works - the border is drawn, but I can't focus cmd window. Is it possible to draw border this way and make cmd window focusable?

Comment: Use `WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` window style. Remove case branch for `WM_NCHITTEST`. From the docs: _"If the layered window has the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT extended window style, the shape of the layered window will be ignored and the mouse events will be passed to the other windows underneath the layered window."_

Comment: @zett42, thanks. Looks like we've almost finished. The last question: if cmd window is maximized, there is no top and bottom border lines and one left (or right line, depend on position) is drawn on the second display (I've got 2 physical displays), but when cmd window is not maximized - everything works fine. How to make it works properly in maximized state? P.S. updated source code

Comment: Yeah, maximized windows have coordinates bigger than the screen (this is how the system "removes" the window border). Check if window has `WS_MAXIMIZED` style, and then use the work area of the monitor instead. Like so: `GetMonitorInfoW(MonitorFromWindow(cmdHanlde,MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &monitorInfo);`, then use `monitorInfo.rcWork`.

Comment: @zett42, Thanks for the help. I changed the code a little to make border flashing and to make border adjust to window size (I implemented it using timers). Everything works fine (when I resize window borders is resized respectively), but if I maximize or minimize window then border disappears. Could you please look at the updated code and try to find the reason?

Comment: Works for me, if I maximize the console window before launching the test app. You have to find a way to always position the frame window above the target window in z-order.

Comment: @zett42, in this case it works for me as well. I mean that when I maximize console app in run time, then the border isn't drawn.Can I use SetWindowPos for this purpose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182186/discussion-between-zett42-and-rudolfninja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the problem with the following code:

```
const COLORREF MY_COLOR_KEY = RGB(255, 128, 0);
HWND cmdHanlde = NULL;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdWindowUpdate = 1;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdFrameColor = 2;
bool tick = false;
bool minimized = false;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyTransparentFrame";
    wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;

    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
           PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            RECT rc{}; GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, tick ? RGB(255, 128, 1) : RGB(255, 201, 14));
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(MY_COLOR_KEY);
            HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
            HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);

            Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);

            if (hOldPen)
                SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
            if (hOldBrush)
                SelectObject(hdc, hOldBrush);
            if (hPen)
                DeleteObject(hPen);
            if (hBrush)
                DeleteObject(hBrush);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            if (wp == timerIdWindowUpdate)
            {
                WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement = { sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT), };
                if (::GetWindowPlacement(cmdHanlde, &windowPlacement))
                {
                    if (windowPlacement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
                        || !IsWindowVisible(cmdHanlde))
                    {
                        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
                        minimized = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RECT rect = {};
                        DwmGetWindowAttribute(cmdHanlde, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rect, sizeof(rect));
                        MONITORINFO monInfo;
                        monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
                        GetMonitorInfoW(MonitorFromWindow(cmdHanlde, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &monInfo);
                        if (cmdHanlde != NULL && ::IsZoomed(cmdHanlde))
                        {
                            rect.left = monInfo.rcWork.left;
                            rect.top = monInfo.rcWork.top;
                            rect.bottom = monInfo.rcWork.bottom > rect.bottom ? rect.bottom : monInfo.rcWork.bottom;
                            rect.right = monInfo.rcWork.right > rect.right ? rect.right : monInfo.rcWork.right;
                        }
                        if (minimized)
                        {
                            ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, cmdHanlde, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                            minimized = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ::SetWindowPos(cmdHanlde, hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                            ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
                            SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (wp == timerIdFrameColor)
            {
                tick = !tick;
                ::RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
        }

        return 0;
    };

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_LAYERED |     WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, wc.lpszClassName, L"", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED,
    0, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    ::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdWindowUpdate, 50, NULL);
    ::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdFrameColor, 500, NULL);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, MY_COLOR_KEY, 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    cmdHanlde = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

May be it is not the best solution, but it works for me. Could you please take a look on it and tell if there something to improve?

Comment: There is still the problem, that you can no longer bring the console window to front, if another window is in the foreground.

Comment: @zett42, unfortunately you're right =( I can bring the window to the front after minimize, but not if another window is in the foreground. Any ides how to solve it? Check if window is overlapped and then use this bool flag in the same way?

Comment: I don't really have a good idea. I would ask this as a new question: "How to keep a window always in front of another applications window".

Answer (score 4):

You can't draw directly on another window, because the system may refresh the window at any time, overwriting your drawing.

To make your drawing persistent, create a [layered window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows), positioned on top of the other window.

1. Create the window with [`WS_EX_LAYERED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) flag.
2. Pass a color key to [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes).
3. In your `WM_PAINT` handler, draw the inside of the rectangle with the color key (by using it for the brush). Everything you draw with the color key will become transparent. Draw the border of the rectangle with the desired color (by using it for the pen).

Here is a minimal example to get you started. The frame can be moved around by drag-n-drop.

Note there is no error handling to keep the sample code concise. You should check the return value of each Windows API call.

```
#include <windows.h>

const COLORREF MY_COLOR_KEY = RGB( 255, 0, 255 );

int APIENTRY wWinMain( 
    HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInst*/, LPWSTR /*lpCmdLine*/, int nCmdShow )
{
    WNDCLASSW wc{ sizeof( wc ) };
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( nullptr, IDC_ARROW );
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>( COLOR_BTNFACE + 1 );
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyTransparentFrame";

    wc.lpfnWndProc = []( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp ) -> LRESULT
    {
        switch( msg )
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

                RECT rc{}; GetClientRect( hwnd, &rc );

                HPEN hPen = CreatePen( PS_SOLID, 20, GetSysColor( COLOR_HIGHLIGHT ) );
                HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush( MY_COLOR_KEY );
                HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject( hdc, hPen );
                HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = SelectObject( hdc, hBrush );

                Rectangle( hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom );

                if( hOldPen )
                    SelectObject( hdc, hOldPen );
                if( hOldBrush )
                    SelectObject( hdc, hOldBrush );
                if( hPen )
                    DeleteObject( hPen );
                if( hBrush )
                    DeleteObject( hBrush );

                EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
            }
            break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

            case WM_NCHITTEST:
                return HTCAPTION;  // to be able to drag the window around
            break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProcW( hwnd, msg, wp, lp );
        }

        return 0;       
    };

    RegisterClassW( &wc );

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW( WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, L"", WS_POPUP,
                         200, 200, 800, 600, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr );

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hwnd, MY_COLOR_KEY, 255, LWA_COLORKEY );
    ShowWindow( hwnd, nCmdShow );

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage( &msg, nullptr, 0, 0 ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I edited your code to make it draw border around cmd window, but unfortunately borders is drawn behind the cmd window, but not on top of it. I added the code I've ot now in the initial post. What should I change to draw border on top of cmd's window?